# Perform Action on specific date

Tags: java, android

I would like to display a UI or splash screen on a specific date , for example display a Santa Claus themed UI on Christmas... I am a beginner and all my research has been no good..

Comment: Do you want to create an event that will execute whatever function (let's say the UI one), or check the date every single time you open the APP?

Comment: yes i want it to check the date when the app is opened, then display the UI

Comment: You might want to use "Calendar", it gives you the possibility to check the current date with year, hour, minute, seconds, ... accuracy.

Comment: Any tutorial recommendations on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google API of Calendar to Sync Dates and generate event to perform action